# Reskit patchObject - extract the object on php server side

Tags: php, ios, restkit

I'm trying to handle ios reskit 2.x request on php
I send the request this way

```
[objectManager putObject:obj path:url parameters:params..
```

I do find the parameters I sent in params by checking

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

But where can't I find the "obj" - the object that I'm trying to update (Same thing happens with patchObject)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RKObjectRequestOperation was missing